# NSNumber as stored object in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have an algorithm that worked fine until I decided to make the local variable into a class object. The code is:

```
NSArray*parseLine=[newline componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
float percentx=[[parseLine objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

//this NSLog prints fine and shows good values for all three items
NSLog(@"parsline:%@ and %@ and percentx: %f",[parseLine objectAtIndex:0], [parseLine objectAtIndex:1], percentx);

[self.data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:percentx] forKey:[parseLine objectAtIndex:0]];

//this NSLog shows (null) for the  [self.data objectForKey:]
NSLog(@"%@ %f %@", [parseLine objectAtIndex:0] ,percentx, [self.data objectForKey:[parseLine objectAtIndex:0]]);
```

I'm baffled how  `[self.data objectForKey:key]` could be null when the `setObject` statement for this `NSMutableDictionary` object called "data" is using valid items. The `NSNumber` is perhaps the issue, but all of this worked fine when "data" was just a locally alloc/init object.

In fact, "data" is not sent data at all. Later I can do this:

```
 NSLog(@"%i",[data count]);
```

And it returns 0.

Comment: Most probably you’ve got the `data` initialization wrong and `data` is `nil` inside the method? You can `NSParameterAssert(data)` to make sure.

Comment: How do I use NSParamaterAssert? I tried to NSLog it to see its output (presumably as a BOOL) but no luck.

Comment: You just pass a condition that should be true, and if it's not, the statement will blow up. Non-nil object is considered true, nil is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i see the problem, you don't quite have a solid understanding of how ivars and properties work. TRY THIS:

In your .h file...

```
@interface YourClassName
    NSMutableDictionary *data;
@end

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *data;
```

In your .m file...

```
@implementation YourClassName

@synthesize data

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame {
    // Other init code here
    self.data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];  
}
```

Now you can reference self.data everywhere in your class.

don't forget [data release]; in the dealloc method.

Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks, you were right there was a concept here i wasn't getting. haven't used a data collection as an instance variable before. i've used ints, floats, etc which do not require this init activity, and i've used other classes i created, but i should have known better! appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Is data marked as retain in your header? self.data is not necessarily equivalent to data by itself as self.data is a property for the ivar data.

Perhaps post how you are initializing self.data?

Comment: The header says this (with an appropriate @synthesize in the implementation): `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary* data;` I have also tried both self.data and just data by itself and it makes no difference.

Comment: And in your init are you doing self.data = `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];` OR `data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` ?

Comment: It was my understanding that an @property that uses "retain" automatically allocates memory; i've never had to use alloc/init in addition to "retain" in any other project. if "data" is a retained instance variable of my class, doesn't that set it up for use in this algorithm?

Comment: right if you use self.someVar it does retain automatically if your property is set to. if you just do someVar = blah, you are referencing the ivar and it needs retain.

Comment: so then why would this be an initializing problem if I am using both "self" and "retain"? I would agree at this point that somehow my ivar "data" is nil, but it makes no sense to my why that would be.

Comment: I think you are confusing retaining and initialization. When you declare a retained property, all you get is the accessor methods — you still have to initialize the property yourself.

Comment: Just paste your initialization code for data in here. That should help solve things.

Comment: The only thing I can do to get the object "data" to actually fill up as planned is to run this: `NSMutableDictionary*data=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
` however, this ends up treating "data" as a locally defined variable, not an ivar that works in other methods. I tried putting this into the initWithFrame method, but that did not initialize it for use in the other methods.

Comment: I need some more space to explain, so i just added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a dictionary and assign it to `self.data` prior to using `self.data`, for example, during your class's designated initializer (assumed to be `-init` for this example):

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return self;

    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

Almost all messages to `nil` return 0/NO/false/NULL/nil/Nil. (Some messages have undefined effects when sent to a `nil` object/`Nil` class.) This is how you can get a 0 count and a `nil` object for your key: you have a `nil` dictionary.